# Using intsvy to generate weighted means in PISA2018 data

Tags: r, weighted-average

I am trying to use the intsvy package to calculate a weighted mean by country and gender for Maths capability from plausible values but I keep receiving the same error message.

> genderMath <- pisa.mean.pv(pvlabel = "MATH", by = c("CNT", "ST004D01T"), data = stud2018)
>
> Error in weighted.mean.default(data[[k]],
>   data[[paste0(config$variables$weightBRR,  :    'x' and 'w' must have
>   the same length

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't found an answer yet, you might want to try the following:

```
pisa2015.mean.pv(pvlabel = "MATH", by = c("CNT", "ST004D01T"), data = stud2018)
```

I had the same error coming up and this solved the problem for me.